# Problems passing in a char[][] to execvp

Tags: c

I am trying to iterate over some input (which are commands and arguments), split the input into individual strings, then pass that input into `execvp()`.

I am having trouble as `execvp()` wants a `(char*, char*[])` as its arguments. I am passing in `(char*, char[][])` which I thought was the same thing but it isn't liking it.

I would use a `char*[]` but I don't know how big the strings are prior to it running, so that is the reason I didn't use it. So obviously if I use `char*[]`, I get a seg fault when I try and access elements of the `char*`'s.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
//input
char *line = "echo hello there what is";
int count = 0;

//store arguments
char args[6][10];
int argCount = 0;

//store temp string from input
char temp[100];
int tempCount = 0;

//word(string) size
int wordSize = 0;

/*
 Here I iterate over the input, storing each string I find in args
 all the above variables help me do that.
 */

execvp(args[0], args);

printf("Error: It didnt work\n");
```

Hopefully that is clear and a valid question, let me know if you want me to add the code of me turning the input into `args`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of arrays of `char` is not the same as an array of pointers to arrays of `char`. `execvp()` expects the latter, with a null pointer as its last element, passing the former has undefined behavior.

You must construct an array of pointers, either allocated from the heap or defined with automatic storage (*on the stack*), initialize it with pointers to argument strings and pass this array to `execvp()`.

Note also that `echo` is both a shell internal command and an executable file in the path.

Here is your code fragment modified accordingly (without the parse code, which is still yours to write):

```
    //input "echo hello there what is";
    //arguments array
    char *args[6];

    /*
     * Here you should iterate over the input, storing each string you find 
     * on the command line into `args` and terminate with a null pointer...
     */

    args[0] = "echo";
    args[1] = "hello";
    args[2] = "there";
    args[3] = "what";
    args[4] = "is";
    args[5] = NULL;

    execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: Most systems have an `echo` command in either `/bin` or `/usr/bin` — indeed, I think POSIX requires it.  You’re right that most shells treat it as a built-in command, but it is also an external command.  And yes, that opens the door to different behaviours.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point! Answer amended. It is amazing how one can learn something new everyday after all these years...

Answer (score 1):

You can use *two* arrays:

```
char real_args[6][10];  // Six strings of up to nine characters each
...
char *args[] = {
    real_args[0],
    real_args[1],
    real_args[2],
    real_args[3],
    real_args[4],
    real_args[5],
    NULL  // Must be terminated by a null pointer
};
```

Use `real_args` for the actual arguments, and then pass `args` to `execvp`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up just using a ```char*[]```and each time I need to store the temp into it, ```malloc``` the ```sizeof(char)*sizeof(temp)``` so the temp will fit into the ```char*[]```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I worked out how to use a `char*[]` instead of a `char[][]` and successfully put it into `execvp()`.

Notes for the code below: I keep track of how long the current string is that I am iterating over in `wordSize`.

```
    //input
    char* line = "echo hello there what is";
    int count = 0;

    //store arguments
    char* args[10];
    int argCount = 0;

    //store temp string from input
    char temp[100];
    int tempCount = 0;

    //word size
    int wordSize = 0;

    while(line[count] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[count] == ' ' || line[count + 1] == '\0')
        {
            /*
              As I don't know how big each string will be, I can 
              allocate it here as I know how big the string is through wordSize
            */
            args[argCount] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(wordSize +1));
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }



    //terminate args with 0
    args[argCount] = 0;

    execvp(args[0], args);

    printf("Error: It didnt work\n");
```